# Python redis server. Expand the number of redis databases

Tags: python

I am using a python redis server. My application needs more than 16 databases, which is the maximum number of databases allowed by redis.

Is there a method to expand the number of redis databases to reach, say, 30 databases?

In an alternative method, I copy the redis dump and paste it into another directory. After that I, create another redis dump.

How can I deal with the two redis dumps in the same script (program)?

Comment: Could you specify which python redis library you are using?
Is the limit on redis or on the python library that you are using?

Comment: I tried to make the post more clear, especially in the wording and the grammar.

Answer (score 0):

yes you must go to redis.conf file and edit it.
this file usually is in this path:
/etc/redis.conf
in this file you see a section like this:

```
databases 16
```

you can increase this number to 30.
after saving this file you must restart your device with this command:

```
sudo systemctl restart redis
```

and after that you can check status of redis server:

```
sudo systemctl status redis
```

you can see more on this link:
https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/redis/install-and-configure-redis-on-centos-7/